# Why can't I add a y-axis to my d3 graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a y axis to my d3 graph but it will not show up.  I'm not sure if there's a bug in my d3 code but I will post and let me know if anything stands out here.

```
var max_width = (d3.max(dailyClicks).toString().length + 6) * 4 + 1,
    w = $('#dailySales').innerWidth(),
    h = 230,
    margin = 20,
    y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(dailyClicks)]).range([margin, h - margin]),
    x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, dailyClicks.length]).range([margin, w - margin - max_width]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var vis = d3.select("#dailySales")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var g = vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + max_width + ", 228)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Maybe the axis is somewhere off screen?

Comment: Yea I tried using translate to move it over, still can't see anything.

Comment: Could you post a complete example please?